# Running SSIS Package simultaneously on 2 different servers

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, ssis

I have made a SSIS package which takes data from source through a stored procedure and saving it  in my  tables  through a stored procedure in  destination side.
Destination and Source are at different  server. 
So  basically i have an Insert Stored Procedure at Source  and an Insert Stored Procedure at destination.
I have two different  servers  Server 1(dev server) and Server 2(test server).
i want  to use the same SSIS package  without needing to change  the schema names and server names  ( Transferring  data from  there  dev server to my dev server  OR  their test server to my test server)

How to proceed for this  and what all steps to follow .?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using DataFlow tasks to move the data from Source to Destination? Or are you using the "Execute SQL Task" to execute your stored procedures?

Are you running the SSIS package manually or is it being scheduled?

Here are your options:
1. Make a copy of the DataFlow with Dev connections and then change it to connect to Test Server.
2. Setup Package configurations utilizing Environment Variable and SSIS Config table.

Comment: it is been scheduled.. and i want to follow  2nd option.. please guide me through that process